# Reduce karma required for commenting

Tags: ros, meta, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently there is the issue, that new users with only few karma can't post comments (on other people's answers)([example](http://answers.ros.org/question/51908/xtion-empty-device-id/#54333)).
As a result some post comments as answers, since there is no other way.

If this is true, could we lower the amount of karma required for commenting?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54550/reduce-karma-required-for-commenting/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2062 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-09**:
Seems like a good idea to me, as long as we can avoid spam comments, which are mostly karma 1.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-02-14**:
Related to this, low karma user not being able to paste URL is becoming troublesome...often it makes difficult to track which tutorial page the questioner is talking about.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-14**:
I'd like to allow any links to ros.org even with 0 karma, if that is somehow possible to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've dropped it to 3 from 10.  If we get spam it'll have to be raised.  There's not as good a moderating mechanism on comments.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-02-12**:
Is there a separate karma requirement for commenting within own questions? In my opinion this should be always allowed to not force new users to post answers if they only want to respond to other given answers.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-02-12**:
Out of curiosity: I assume a spam bot can create as many questions as it wants. If that is true, why do we add an extra barrier to commenting? Couldn't we just lower the required karma to 1?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-02-21**:
Since the karma limit for commenting also causes "comment answers" on Gazebos Q&A, I went over to the Askbot site planning to raise this issue. But then I saw that they lowered the required karma for commenting to 1 (= new users karma amount) already (see [here](http://askbot.org/en/faq/)).

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-02-21**:
Please, please set ROS Answers karma limit for commenting also to 1! It's tiresome to keep people reminding to not uses answers for comments and they have to reply that they can't comment!